# How to get the bytes occupied by the whole value?

Tags: memory, rust

```
use std::mem;
impl Solution {
    pub fn find_substring(s: String, words: Vec<String>) -> Vec<i32> {
        let mut result: Vec<i32> = vec![23, 234, 243,  23, 26, 24, 2345];
        println!("{}", mem::size_of_val(&result));
        result
    }
}
```

But I'm getting 24 for the println!. I'm not sure what 24 bytes refers to. I want to know how to get the total memory the result vector is consuming, including the bytes that store the values and also any additional bytes required for the data structure itself. How can I find that?

Answer (score 5):

The 24 bytes (in a 64bits platform) are just for the size of the struct's fields: pointer, length, capacity.

There's no general way to follow all internal pointers and determine the "real" space used in memory. There's not even an obvious general definition of such space (what do you do if a field is a `Rc` ?).

What's possible is to define a function to get the size used by vectors, which you get by adding the capacity multiplied by the contained element type's size:

```rust
pub fn size_of_vec<T>(vec: &Vec<T>) -> usize {
    std::mem::size_of_val(vec) + vec.capacity() * std::mem::size_of::<T>()
}

fn main() {
    let mut result: Vec<i32> = vec![23, 234, 243,  23, 26, 24, 2345];
    dbg!(size_of_vec(&result));
}
```

Of course, if the `T` type refers to heap reserved space, this `size_of_vec` function can't account for it.